# Vector multiplication with BLAS' catlas_saxpby not working properly

Tags: c, ios, blas

I am trying to have two arbitrary length vectors (typical length will be 2048) and multiply element by element. So Z[n] = X[n] * Y[n] for all n.

The code I have setup to test is fairly basic:

```
float inputX[4] = { 2, 4, 8, 16 };
float inputY[4] = { 2, 4, 8, 16 };

catlas_saxpby(4, 1, inputX, 1, 1, inputY, 1);
```

The result goes into inputY, and the result is

```
4.000000, 8.000000, 16.000000, 32.000000
```

Which if they were multiplying it should be 4, 16, 64, 256. But it looks like it is adding.

So this is not doing what I expect, and the documentation doesn't give me enough information to figure what it is doing.

Any ideas?

```
Apple's documentation for BLAS says this: 

Computes the product of two vectors, scaling each one separately (single-precision).

void catlas_saxpby (
   const int N,
   const float alpha,
   const float *X,
   const int incX,
   const float beta,
   float *Y,
   const int incY
);
Parameters
N
Number of elements in the vector.
alpha
Scaling factor for X.
X
Input vector X.
incX
Stride within X. For example, if incX is 7, every 7th element is used.
beta
Scaling factor for Y.
Y
Input vector Y.
incY
Stride within Y. For example, if incY is 7, every 7th element is used.
Discussion
On return, the contents of vector Y are replaced with the result.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple documentation is mistaken.  The `saxpby` function computes the expression `alpha*X + beta*Y` for scalars `alpha` and `beta` and vectors `X` and `Y`.

I don't think there's a function available to compute the element-wise product of two vectors, since that's not a common operation in linear algebra.  You could take the diagonal of the outer product, but that's a severe waste of effort since it computes the entire outer product (N<sup>2</sup> multiplications instead of N).

Comment: I think I am going to be stuck using neon intrinsics or a for loop. I will likely try both and see what is faster.

Answer (score 3):

As **Adam Rosenfield** said, the documentation is incorrect.  Please file a bug.

That aside, there are some corrections to the rest of his answer.  First, `saxpby` computes `alpha * X + beta * Y`.  Second, and more useful for you: there is no function in BLAS that does what you want, but there is exactly such a function in vDSP, which is also part of the Accelerate.framework: [vDSP_vmul](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: After succeeding with using some neon intrinsics, I guess I will have to use vmul now :P. Thank you for showing me that. It is certainly more portable.